# Mocha & SuperTest Tests Timing out

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, supertest

I've got a problem whereas sometimes my tests fail due to the asserts being run before the response comes back here in my integration tests:

```
   it('should find all countries when no id is specified', co.wrap(function *(){
        var uri = '/countries';
        var response = yield request.get(uri);

        should.exist(response.body);
        response.status.should.equal(200);
    }));
```

Not sure how to tweak mocha or supertest to wait or if I should use a promise here or what.  I'm using generators with mocha here.

Adding a longer timeout to mocha does absolutely nothing.  The query behind this particular test takes a bit longer than my other tests.  My other tests run just fine.

Comment: A quick look shows that `co.wrap` uses promises everywhere. Are you sure the `response` is actually a response and not a promise? You might try using `co(...)` instead of `co.wrap(...)` to get a plain object from `yield`.

Comment: What is the exact error message you get when your test fails? Supertest has its *own* timeout which is different from Mocha's timeout. The two are *independent*. You could set Mocha's timeout to 3 hours and supertest would still timeout. (By the way `co.wrap` is correct.)

Comment: It goes immediately to yellow

Comment: Co will not work. Already tried that a long time ago..  Someone mentioned to use co-wrap and ever since I was able to finally run my mocha test via generators